# Fortify Software Security Center 21.2.0 Unable process the Fortify_Process_Seed_Bundle-2021_Q4_0001.zip during initial setup

Tags: windows-server-2016, tomcat9, mysql8

I am trying to set up Fortify SSC 21.2.0 for a demo, and I am
having a bit of trouble getting the database seeded.

The following describes my set-up specifications and
my progress so far. Apparently the issue at this
point as far as I can tell is that SSC is trying to "seed" the
SSC database with actual values but there seems to be missing
required table(s).

Any help regarding this matter would be greatly appreciated!!!
Thanks!!!!

Specifications:

- Windows 2016 Server
- Running all applications with full administrative rights
- Fortify SSC 21.2.0 deployment bundle
- Apache Tomcat 9.0.5
- MySQL 8.0.28

1. Fortify SSC deployment successful

- Navigate to http://localhost:8000/ssc
- Fortify SSC maintenance splash page
- Fortify Software Security Center Setup via Administrators Link

2. init.token

- token generated by install script
- sucessfully logged into "Fortify Software Security Center Setup" using generated token

3. Uploaded fortify.licence file

- Configuration File Directory :

  - C:\Users\myusername.fortify\ssc

4. Fortify software Security Center URL

- http://localhost:8000/ssc
- HTTP Host Header Validation : Off
- Global Search : Off

5. Database Setup

- jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ssc?sessionVariables=collation_connection=utf8_bin
- maximum idle connections : 50
- maximum active connections : 100
- maximum wait time(ms): 60000
- Test connection from Fortify SSC to database is successful
- Ran create-tables.sql

- Line 2323 of create-tables.sql failed:

- CREATE PROCEDURE updateExistingWithLatest(p_scan_id INT p_projectVersion_Id INT, p_engineType varchar(20)).....
  "already exists"
- Database seeding:

  - Fortify_Process_Seed_Bundle-2021_Q4_001.zip
- Seeding Results:

  - Unable to process the Fortify_Process_Seed_Bundle-2021_Q4_0001.zip
    Seeding failed: Unable to seed all init seed bundles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.
There were two separate issues here that needed to be addressed.

- Collation configuration
- File system Case-Sensitivity Requirements

MySQL by default uses uff-8,and it was assumed by me that Fortify SSC would use uff-8.  SSC requires character set of latin-1.

Fortify SSC also requires all databases and tables  written to it's backend to be case-sensitive. Windows Server 2016 does not support case-sensitive file reading/writing.  MySQl within this context must be configured for force case sensitivity BEFORE the SSC database is created; via the my.ini MySQL configuration file.